# Unique mask on nested arrays APL

Tags: arrays, apl

I am trying to use the new unique mask function added in Dyalog v. 18, but it seems that it doesn't work on nested arrays.

```
      ≠¨('aabbcc')('ddeeff')
SYNTAX ERROR: The function requires a left argument
      ≠¨('aabbcc')('ddeeff')
      ∧
```

I figured it would return this

```
┌→──────────┬───────────┐
│1 0 1 0 1 0│1 0 1 0 1 0│
└~─────────→┴~─────────→┘
```

but maybe I'm not understanding how it works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm quite green with APL so I can't say from experience, but the help says "*Unique Mask R←≠Y, Y may be any array.*" which suggests it should work on nested arrays. It does the same for me as it does for you, suggesting it's not down to any config changes you might have made. As an alternative `≠⍤⊢¨ ('aabbcc') ('ddeeff')` works to get the result you expect. Or without the parens.

Comment: Please see edit ↓

Answer (score 0):

You've found a bug. The Each operator `¨` seems to try to apply Unequal instead of Unique Mask. I've logged it as issue number 18447, and will update this post when the issue is addressed.

**Edit 22 Jun 2020:** This bug has now been fixed and a new interpreter can be downloaded from [dyalog.com](https://dyalog.com).